# Docker Compose on ASP.NET Core 2.x and Nginx with HTTPS/SSL

Tags: docker, nginx, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to use Nginx as the web server for my ASP.NET Core 2.x project using [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) as base. I just omitted the server_name(for multitenancy about to be implemented in the web project). All of HTTP/80 requests will be redirected to HTTPS/443.

I created an ASP.NET Core 2.x with Angular project and enabled "Configure for HTTPS", then added Docker support which it created the default Dockerfile for the project and a project for Docker-compose.

In the Dockerfile, I removed the auto-generated port numbers, instead exposed port 80 and 443:

```
#EXPOSE 61876
#EXPOSE 44340
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Then created a file and named it as nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;    

    server {
        listen 443;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         $scheme://erp.web;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

Then modified the docker-compose.yml(version 3.4) into this:

```
services:
  erp.web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}erpweb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Erp.Web/Dockerfile

  proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

with docker-comspoe.override.yml like this:

```
services:
  erp.web:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443
    ports:
      - "80" #"61876:80"
      - "443" #"44340:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

When I try to browse https://localhost, it says it can't reach the server. Also when I try to check the list of Docker containers, the Nginx server still uses port 80, while my web app project has these ports:

```
some-random-port(currently 32771)->80, some-other-random-port(32770 for now)->443
```

Comment: did you found any solution eSPiYa?

Comment: @Arjun still haven't. I put this on hold for now, it is just a practice project but I hope I would learn how to do it soon because of the upcoming project I would handle in a few months.

Comment: I am working on this on possibly can share the solution for the same eSPiya. I am almost there except deploying in AWS ECS fargate. Let me know in case if you need a solution for this.

Comment: @Arjun please do share once you're done. Thanks!

Comment: i am done with my changes and its working like a charm. will share the github link soon here.

Comment: please answer or close the question if the issue is resolved